# How to stop Maven build using Checkstyle

Tags: java, maven, checkstyle

I've managed to use Maven with Checkstyle plugin and I can create reports on my code. But what I want really to have is that I can stop the build process of Maven if there are any errors on style check.

So far my `pom.xml` looks like below:

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.company.app</groupId>
  <artifactId>my-app</artifactId>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>my-app</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>log4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
      <version>1.2.12</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <reporting>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.8</version>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </reporting>
</project>
```

How can I reach my goal here? Our team wants to have strict coding style standards so I have to use it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To achieve what you want, you need to use the maven-checkstyle-plugin in the build lifecycle in addition to the reporting lifecycle:

```xml
<project>
...
<build>
...
 <plugins>
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.8</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <phase>process-sources</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>check</goal>
        </goals>
      </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
      <failsOnError>true</failsOnError>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
 </plugins>
</build>
</project>
```

Comment: thnx man, is there a way to print the results to command line, rather than writing to an xml file?

Comment: @LostMohican: Yes, you can add `<consoleOutput>true</consoleOutput>` to the configuration section to enable console output. For more options, you can have a look there: http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-checkstyle-plugin/check-mojo.html

Answer (score 22):

I realize that there has been some time since this question was asked, but none of the above answers resolved this for me.

In order for the build to fail on violations, I had to change the `violationSeverity` value from its default `error` to `warning` in the `configuration` block, similar to:

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.17</version>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.puppycrawl.tools</groupId>
            <artifactId>checkstyle</artifactId>
            <version>7.5.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>validate</id>
            <phase>validate</phase>
            <configuration>
                <configLocation>checkstyle.xml</configLocation>
                <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                <consoleOutput>true</consoleOutput>
                <failsOnError>false</failsOnError>
                <failOnViolation>true</failOnViolation>
                <violationSeverity>warning</violationSeverity>
                <linkXRef>false</linkXRef>
            </configuration>
            <goals>
                <goal>check</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Also, please note that we have established a slightly modified version of styles (defined in `checkstyle.xml`), mostly based on the latest `google_checks.xml`. However, in order for this to work, the `com.puppycrawl.tools.checkstyle` dependency had to be updated as well.

Comment: This fixed it for me.  Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You could try setting the [failsOnError property](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-checkstyle-plugin/check-mojo.html#failsOnError) e.g.

```xml
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.8</version>
    <configuration>
    <failsOnError>true</failsOnError>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
```