# How to fail Maven build if code contains any TODOs

Tags: maven, continuous-integration, todo

We add `TODO`s to our code whenever there is a dependency from another team member. Then we slowly resolve all `TODO`s until our code works. How can I make our build fail when there are any unresolved `TODO`s ?

Comment: I would take a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42403224/296328 furthermore that sounds more like a `FIXME` than a `TODO`...

Comment: @khmarbaise this is what i was looking for. thanks

Comment: Also take into consideration the suggestion of JF Meier...

Answer (score 0):

Write a Junit test for your todo. It will fail if  the the todo was not resolved.